# how to Create a new file called appcenter-post-clone.sh for deploying to microsoft app center?

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-app-center

i wanna deploy my corporate-databse iOS app to a group of people only through a link, for now i am trying to do it via microsoft app center, i have followed the steps of this link as far as creating provisioning profile and certificate for the app... however when it gets to the step of creating a new file i dont know what it means and how to do it honestly, what kind of file does it mean and are those commands or do i just create "the file"and copy paste it in it? can someone help me on how to do this step?

here's the link
https://buildflutter.com/deploying-flutter-apps-via-appcenter/

heres a picture of the step:
[image]

Comment: You can try to create a file `touch appcenter-post-clone.sh` in the root of your iOS project and then insert script to it which shown on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You create a file called appcenter-post-clone.sh yourself and put it into android/app/ path. Copy content for this file from here: https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/blob/master/sample-build-scripts/flutter/android-build/appcenter-post-clone.sh

then, you have to create such file inside ios/ folder and copy its content from here: https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/blob/master/sample-build-scripts/flutter/ios-build/appcenter-post-clone.sh

more info: https://medium.com/@rakhimov.sardorbek/flutter-apps-ci-cd-using-appcenter-ab68b4aee30f